# asp.net web service OneWay definition not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

When I specify `<SoapDocumentMethod(OneWay:=True)>` on my webservice it doesn't seem to get called.  If I remove that the webservice works properly.  Also, everything works fine on the development machine just not on the server.

Here is my web method:

```
<SoapDocumentMethod(OneWay:=True)> _
<WebMethod()> _
Public Sub Write(ByVal processGroupId As Integer) 
    xslClass.xslHelper.writeDatabase(processGroupId) 
End Sub
```

Here is my calling code:

```
    Dim svc As New svcWriteFiles.WriteDatabaseService
    svc.WriteAsync(e.CommandArgument)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How have you determined that it's not getting called?

Comment: The service writes out a file to the system when it gets called.  This isn't happening when OneWay is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out.  First I turned on tracing following these instructions:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb885203.aspx

This showed me that when oneWay is turned on I was getting security exceptions.  (I don't really understand why I would get that only for oneWay but whatever).

I then add security the folders where I was having security issues.  (C:\Windows\temp)

Hope this helps someone.